# Making a 3D plot of multiple column vectors

Tags: matlab

I have multiple vectors of varying lengths that I would like to plot next to each other in 3D space in Matlab.

As an example:
Say I have three vectors:
X is a 5x2 vector,
Y is a 10x2 vector and
Z is a 15x2 vector.

Each element of every vector has the format:
x value, y value
but the x values of the various vectors do not match.

I would like to plot these vectors in 3D space, next to each other. The reason why I don't want to plot them using "hold" is because most of the data have the same values, but I would like to see how many of the plots have the same value at a specific time.

I hope my questions makes sense. Please just ask if anyone is unsure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for the function `ribbon`.

Documentation: http://www.mathworks.fr/help/techdoc/ref/ribbon.html

[image]

**EDIT:**

if your x's do not have the same length, you can combine it with `interp1` as follow:

```
x1=0:0.1:1;
x2=0:0.02:1.5;
y1=x1.^2;
y2=sqrt(x2);
y2=interp1(x2,y2,x1);
ribbon(x1',[y1;y2]')
```

Comment: I've looked at the function ribbon, but I couldn't figure out how I would actually go about generating the different ribbons. Could you please add a code example using the example vectors I gave, keeping in mind that these vectors are not of the same length or x values?

Comment: Sorry Oli, but I'm still not clear on what you mean. Please use the X, Y and Z vectors I defined in my question. In your answer, I do not see any mention of the X, Y and Z vectors that I already have and want to plot. And my question is actually for any number of vectors. Currently, I have 37 (x value, y value) vectors that I want to plot next to each other. Thanks a lot for time, I really appreciate it.